# Filtering MediaStore to only include a specific folder's images but without MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA (which is deprecated)

Tags: java, android, mediastore

My app shows the user all photos from their device using MediaStore.
However, the use case of my app might make the user want to get photos from a specific folder only.

So I want to limit the MediaStore query to a specific directory the user has provided. The easiest way to do this is something like this:

```
mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",//selection
    new String[] {"%The_folder_here%"},//selectionArgs
    null
);
```

But MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA is deprecated. So I need something else.
What can I use instead?

Comment: Use the .RELATIVE_PATH column.

Comment: If .DATA works for you then use it. Dont worry.

Comment: Hey have , you figured it out ?

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR I used DATA and Play store accepted my app nevertheless, so you can use it as well I guess.

Comment: Ohhh great Thanks for answering